# How to display a video in a web browser which occupies the exact height of the window?

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I'm trying to display video as a web page which occupies exactly the entire size of the web window.

The width of the video is OK. However, the height of the video is "longer" than it should be (ie. need to be scrolled up to see the bottom part of the video).

I have the following code in the HTML page:

```
<body>
<video id="video" autoplay width="100%" height="100%"></video>
</body>
```

and the following CSS code:

```
html {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

video {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

(The video is controlled by JavaScript and it works, ie. the video plays.)

The **problem** is that the video exceeded the height and it is ***truncated*** (ie. a portion of the bottom part video goes beyond the browser window and needs to scroll up to see it).

**How do I make the window occupying exactly the height of the window (no more, no less - same height of the available viewing space of the web window)? Thanks!**

Comment: Have you tried setting actual values to your html style, then use the 0 margin of video to fill? Also, just a note, because you want all four sides to have 0 margin you can use the shorthand 'margin: 0;'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the video to be always equal to the screen size (which basically makes it responsive), I would solve it like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="video-con">
    <video id="video" autoplay></video>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
video { object-fit: fill; }

.video-con {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -100;
}

#video {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**Live Demo:** [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/0r7padyv/)

Comment: Great answer! I would use "object-fit: cover;" to crop the video, rather that stretching it out of proportion in different devices.

Answer (score 3):

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<video controls> 
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm type=video/webm> 
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv type=video/ogg> 
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 type=video/mp4>
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.3gp type=video/3gp>
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
#video{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<video id="video" autoplay></video>
```